# Setting ContextInfo in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I want to set context info in nhibernate to achieve multitenancy. Now I am firing a stored procedure which will set context info in every connection. But  I came to know that using stored procedures in nhibernate is not a right way. So does Nhibernate have any support for setting context info?

Comment: what kind of contextinfo do you mean? what is the use case?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at DriverConnectionProvider and invoking SET CONTEXT_INFO whenever a new connection is made as in:

http://jasondentler.com/blog/2010/01/exploiting-context_info-for-fun-and-audit